# Why is std::is_const_v evaluated to false here?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, type-traits, c++-concepts

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const):

> If T is a reference type then is_const<T>::value is always false. The
> proper way to check a potentially-reference type for const-ness is to
> remove the reference: is_const<typename remove_reference<T>::type>.

That makes sense for references, because there are no `const` references, there may only be a reference to a constant. But that should not be the case for pointers as they, unlike references, can be `const`. What if I want to check if a template parameter is a `const` pointer to a `const` type?

```
template<typename T>
requires std::is_pointer_v<T> // Ok
         && std::is_const_v<std::remove_pointer_t<T>> // Ok
         // && std::is_const_v<T> // Fails (2)
void foo(T t) { std::cout << *t << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    const int i{5};
    const int* const p{&i};

    static_assert(std::is_const_v<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(p)>>); // Ok
    static_assert(std::is_const_v<decltype(p)>); // Ok (1)

    foo(p);
}
```

Something is wrong here - constraint `(2)` is evaluated to false. But at the same time `static_assert()` `(1)` is evaluated to true. Why is that? Is it somehow related to template parameter deduction?

Comment: Because `std::is_const_v` checks for a top-level const but `const int*` has no top level const. It has a **low-level const**.

Comment: `int const*` is _obviously_ not top level const.

Comment: I'm guessing you were expecting it to behave like `foo<decltype(p)>(p)`, but it doesn't because deducing `T` will always remove top-level `const` like the answers below explain (but I think they might be missing what the disconnect in this question is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, `T` is deduced to be `const int*` for the call `foo(p)`.

---

> Something is wrong here - constraint (2) is evaluated to false. But at the same time static_assert() (1) is evaluated to true. Why is that?

Because `std::is_const_v` checks for a **top-level const** but `const int*` has a **low-level const**(not a *top-level const*).

On the other hand, `decltype(p)` is `const int* const` which has a **top-level const** which is what `std::is_const_v` checks.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it somehow related to template parameter deduction?

Yes, `T t` will never deduce `T` as `const`. Because to the caller the (top-level) `const` is completely unnoticeable.